# Passing DomainUpDown.Value from programmatically generated form to main form

Tags: c#, button, richtextbox, numericupdown

I have a form1 with a `showForm` button that programmatically creates and opens a new `form2` with 4 `DomainUpDown` elements and a `OKBtn` button. I need to pass the value of `DomainUpDown` element using my `OKBtn` from `form2` to `form1` richtextbox.My only diffulty is that question mark at the end. Here is the code snippet :

```
public void showForm_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
       Form frm = new Form();
       frm.Size = new Size(264, 183);
       frm.Name = "MarginSelector";
       frm.Text = "Qiymət ver";
       frm.ShowIcon = false;
       frm.Show();

       DomainUpDown marginRightVal = new DomainUpDown();
       marginRightVal.Location = new Point(150, 100);
       marginRightVal.Size = new Size(42, 40);
       frm.Controls.Add(marginRightVal);
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       {
            marginRightVal.Items.Add(i + "%");
       }

       Button OKBtn = new Button();
       OKBtn.Visible = true;
       OKBtn.Text = "OK";
       OKBtn.Size = new Size(30, 23);
       OKBtn.Location = new Point(96, 109);
       frm.Controls.Add(OKBtn);
       OKBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OKBtn_Click);
}

public void OKBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       textArea.SelectionLength = 0;
       textArea.SelectedText = string.Filter("margin-top: {0} ; \n, ? ");
}
```

Comment: You need to move the `marginRightVal` variable declaration outside of the method so you can also use it in your OKBtn_Click event handler.  Or use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow Hans Passant his suggestion or you can cast the `sender` of the click event to a control, get a reference to the form and iterate over the [`Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to find the control you're looking for. Once found, assign it to a variable and use it in your logic. An implentation could look like this:

```
public void OKBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // assume a Control is the sender
    var ctrl = (Control)sender;
    // on which form is the control?
    var frm = ctrl.FindForm();
    // iterate over all controls
    DomainUpDown domainUpDown = null;
    foreach(var ctr in frm.Controls)
    {
        // check if this is the correct control
        if (ctr is DomainUpDown)
        {
            // store it's reference
            domainUpDown = (DomainUpDown)ctr;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if we have found the control
    if (domainUpDown != null)
    {
        textArea.SelectionLength = 0;
        Debug.WriteLine(domainUpDown.SelectedIndex);
        Debug.WriteLine(domainUpDown.SelectedItem);
        // use the SelectedItem
        textArea.SelectedText = string.Format("margin-top: {0} ; \n,", domainUpDown.SelectedItem );
    }
}
```

If you have multiple controls on your form you better add an unique name to each of them:

```
DomainUpDown marginRightVal = new DomainUpDown();
marginRightVal.Location = new Point(150, 100);
marginRightVal.Size = new Size(42, 40);
marginRightVal.Name = "right";
frm.Controls.Add(marginRightVal);
```

and when you iterate over the control collection you can check for that name:

```
foreach(var ctr in frm.Controls)
{
    // check if this is the correct control
    if (ctr is DomainUpDown)
    {
        // store it's reference
        domainUpDown = (DomainUpDown)ctr;
        if (domainUpDown.Name == "right")
        {
           // do logic for that value
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use the [Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var found = frm.Controls.Find("right", false);
if (found.Length>0)
{
    var rightDomain = (DomainUpDown)found[0];
    // do logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rene! It helped a lot! Now i have to add 3 more DomainUpDowns,but i think i've got the idea!